# custom tableView Model for Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, qt, uitableview, model, pandas

I'm trying to implement a Model in order to display data from a pandas dataframe in a tableView object designed via QT Designer.
I saw some examples here at Stack Overflow showing how to write a simple model for that purpose:

```
import sip
sip.setapi('QString', 1)
sip.setapi('QVariant', 1)

import pandas as pd
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui


class TableModel(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel): 
    def __init__(self, parent=None, *args): 
        super(TableModel, self).__init__()
        self.datatable = None     

    def update(self, dataIn):
        self.datatable = dataIn            

    def rowCount(self, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        return len(self.datatable.index) 

    def columnCount(self, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        return len(self.datatable.columns.values) 

    def data(self, index, role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole):
        if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:            
            i = index.row()
            j = index.column()
            return '{0}'.format(self.datatable.iget_value(i, j))
        else:
            return QtCore.QVariant()
```

However, I cannot succeed in writing any function inside the TableModel class that allows me to edit horizontal and vertical headers in order to display dataframe index (on the rows) and dataframe columns labels (on the columns of the table).
Can anyone please help me with that?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I actually found that this widget produces the results I am wishing:

```
def headerData(self,section,orientation,role=Qt.DisplayRole):
    if role != Qt.DisplayRole:
        return QVariant()          
    if orientation == Qt.Horizontal:
        return self.df.columns.tolist()[section]
    elif orientation == Qt.Vertical:
        return str(self.df.index.tolist()[section])
```

any other, more efficient, ideas?